# Copy Directory and Subdirectories only if String present in name

Tags: bash, directory, copy

I have a few directories:

```
Blue-3.30
Red-Green-5.50
Blue-Red-3.30
BLUE-RED-4.40
A-Blue-3.30
GreenBlue-44.00
```

In this example, how would I copy folders, and their contents, only if they have the word "blue" in their name? I would also like to copy folders where "blue" is present within a compound word (like the folder GreenBlue-44.00)?

Comment: Are there file in these folder that will need to be moved as well?

Comment: Do you want case sensitivity, or not? (`find`'s `-regex` can handle that too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) command like so:

```
find . -type d -iname '*blue*' -exec cp -r {} /destination/dir/path \;
```

`-type d` : Find directories.
`-iname '*blue*'` : Find names matching `blue`, case-insensitive.
`-exec cp -r {} /destination/dir/path \;` : Copy each item to the desired destination directory.

Comment: Thanks! This worked fine for my use case and was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find` command.

`find` command has following options, which are useful for your problem:

- `-regex` (in your case, it can be `.*Blue.*`
- `-type d` (directory only)
- `-maxdept` (you can define which level you'll ask find to search)

Further, you can use `-exec` or pipe to `xargs` to do the copy operation.

More detailed information about those options you can find in manpage.